# customize continue reading in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles

This is the code of continue reading in function.php

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
```

It has a class which named meta-nav I tried to find the class and change it but I couldn't find that. Where is that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change styling of any elements in the style.css file in your theme's folder. Just add:

```
.meta-nav {
    color: red;
    font-size: 3em;
    /* any styling you want! */
}
```

Comment: I know that. It should have this class because it named this class.

Comment: By the way I added them. But nothing changed

Comment: So post link to your Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

When a good theme author creates classes on elements in a template, it is not necessarily to style them. Classes are given to describe the semantics of the element – what the content is.

Therefore you will not necessarily find all classes from the HTML output in the CSS.

However, if you'd like to style the `class="meta-nav"` elements, you need to do is to add a .meta-nav block in the stylesheet, like so:

```
.meta-nav {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Comment: I did that. But nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

"It doesn't work" or "It hasn't changed" tells us nothing. If you expect specific answers to a problem, add specific details - perhaps in the form of a link to your website.

If you need to override certain elements in your CSS, then use the !important rule if nothing seems to be working:

```
.meta-nav {
color:red !important;
font-size:3em !important;
}
```